# What is the purpose of the post request object at the end of my patient resource generated with Synthea?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I have generated a patient with the default settings using [Synthea](https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea). The first entry in the bundle generated is as follows:

```
{
  "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:0100411a-6826-40d8-bfc7-baba56c9945b",
  "resource": {
    // Patient resource here
  },
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "Patient"
  }
}
```

Why does Synthea generate a POST request at the end of each entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this Bundle can be used as a [transaction or a batch](http://hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html#transaction), that is - when the bundle is sent to the server, the server will know what operation (`method`) to do with this resource and on what endpoint (`url`).

Comment: will this post operation create resource with its own unique FHIR id, if bundle posted as transaction?

Comment: Yes, plus all the references from other resources to this one (referring to the urn:uuid:...) will be replaced with that unique id, if the server has implemented transactions correctly.